# how to set the total number of pdf's pages to be generated by using HTMLDoc?

Tags: pdf-generation, htmldoc

I am using HTMLDoc to generate a pdf file. But i want to generate the pdf file of two pages.
In which on first page there should be image and on second page it will contain the HTML file content. Currently I am using this code to generate the pdf file. It is generating a pdf file of one page only and all my content and image is coming on single page only. Here is my code.

```
cmd = "htmldoc --webpage --color --no-toc --footer ... #{@size ? ' --size ' + @size : ''} #{@body_image ? ' --bodyimage ' + @body_image : ''} #{@margins && @margins.size == 4 ? ' --top ' + @margins[0] + ' --right ' + @margins[1] + ' --bottom ' + @margins[2] + ' --left ' + @margins[3] : ''} -f #{@pdf_file} #{html_file}  2>&1"
```

Thanks in advance.
Gaurav Soni

Comment: and i think that "ruby on rails" tag here isn't correct.

Comment: This is the part of code that i used in my application and its running.

Answer (score 1):

From the [**HTMLDOC manual**](https://www.msweet.org/documentation/project1/HTMLDOC.html):

> *HTMLDOC supports many special HTML comments to initiate page breaks, set the header and footer text, and control the current media options.*

So it looks you should insert this special comment into your HTML source at the spot you need a page break:

```
<!-- PAGE BREAK -->
```